# Paperclip gem bug - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, paperclip

I tried building a simple recipe app, however I can't manage to fix one bug:

[image]

I tried installing ImageMagick 6.9.1-0 for Mac OS X 10.5 – 10.10.

However my mac uses OS X EL CAPITAN 10.11.1 and couldn't manage to get it working.

I also read that [it's not safe to use it anymore](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/05/easily-exploited-bug-exposes-huge-number-of-sites-to-code-execution-attacks/).

What would you suggest? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: use homebrew to install imagemagick first

Comment: Do you use [brew](http://brew.sh/)? Do `brew install imagemagick`.

Comment: @Uzbekjon thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install ImageMagick.

First install Homebrew. Open up a terminal window and run:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, ask it to install ImageMagic properly on your system:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

And you have a working copy of ImageMagic.